# Display tiff image in all browser

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, tiff

I am trying to display tiff image in the browser but it is not working when I am trying to read locally or if I am giving URL of any tiff image. Here is my code .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
   xhr.open('GET', " file:///home/aniketshivamtiwari/Desktop/tiffdocument.tif");


   xhr.onload = function (e) {
  var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
  var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
  document.body.append(canvas);
};
xhr.send();
 </script>
```

I am getting this error 
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/aniketshivamtiwari/Desktop/tiffdocument.tif. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ (index):54**

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all, you cant load files from your local machine. Upload the file in your project folder and use absulote or relative reference to that.

i.e.: put the file under images/tiffdocument.tif
xhr.open('GET', "images/tiffdocument.tif");